# Truncate and other operations on the constant in Verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

Very simple example I am stuck with. I want design written in Verilog to return a year *defined* in source as 16-bit format to the outer world using two bytes.

```
`define MY_YEAR 16'd2017
```

then I need to somehow split this constant into two bytes to perform something like this

```
wire [7:0] w_year_byte = w_current_byte ? (`MY_YEAR >> 8) : (`MY_YEAR & 8'hff);
```

For me above expressions with MY_YEAR are not correct as their result is still 16-bit. And this statement does not compile at all...

I know how to do it with vectors, but have never done it before for constants; saw several answers for similar questions on the internet, but still unclear how to make things *properly*. May appear that my approach is totally wrong, will be extremely glad for educating me.

**Update:** my Verilog source is relatively big, and the main idea was to have this year definition at the very beginning of the source file, on the first line, because it will be changed frequently and I would not need to go down to find the value to change.

Reviewing Tom Carpenter's answer I realized I was making stupid mistake trying to declare parameter, local parameter or wire outside of the module (at the top of the source, before module declaration), so I follow his suggestion to have

```
`define MY_YEAR 16'd2017
```

on the first line of the source, and then somewhere after module declaration having

```
wire [15:0] c_MY_YEAR = `MY_YEAR;
```

and then using `c_MY_YEAR[7:0]` and `c_MY_YEAR[15:8]` as usual. Thanks Tom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using `localparam` rather than `'define`.

For example:

```
module blah (

);

localparam MY_YEAR = 16'd2017; //This is a local parameter which cannot be seen or changed outside the module

wire [7:0] w_year_byte = w_current_byte ? MY_YEAR[15:8] : MY_YEAR[7:0];

...

endmodule
```

Remember that with Verilog you are not working with computer programs, you aren't doing things in a procedural fashion, but rather describing hardware. If you want to access the MSB's or the LSB's, you can simply describe that - access them directly with the range selection operator (`[MSB:LSB]`) or part selection operator (`[LSB+:WIDTH]`).

Local parameters have the advantage over `defines in that they can be treated as constant wires - you can access the value of them in the same was as you would access the value of a wire.

Additionally you could easily change your `localparam` to a `parameter` which would then allow you to change the value of the parameter when you instantiate the module - this is one of the building blocks of reusable parameterised modules. If your goal is to have the parameters at the top of the file, this can sort of be accomplished with Verilog 2001 ANSI style module declarations:

```
module blah #(
    parameter MY_YEAR = 16'd2017
)(
    input whatever,
    output bob,
    input cheese
);
...
```

---

If you have your heart set on a `define, you can access it by converting it to a wire. For example:

```
wire [15:0] my_year_wire = `MY_YEAR;
```

Once assigned to a wire you can then access it in the same way as the parameter version above:

```
wire [7:0] w_year_byte = w_current_byte ? my_year_wire[15:8] : my_year_wire[7:0];
```

Comment: It gives error wishing project to be SystemVerilog. I had the same for `wire [15:0] MY_YEAR = 16'd2017`.

Comment: @Anonymous eerm, this is perfectly valid Verilog syntax - what compiler are you using?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed my mistake. I was trying to declare `localparam` and `wire` outside of the module!

Comment: @Anonymous everything must be inside a `module`. `module` is the building block of everything in Verilog.

Comment: Well, the main idea using `define` was to have the constants at the very beginning of the text, in the first line, even before the module declaration.

Comment: If you use parameters, you can sort of accomplish that too using ANSI style port declaration. Just updating my answer.